# Using pgRouting for 'multiple pedestrians' on an existing table of 'students'?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I'm trying to use the pgRouting sample for '[multiple pedestrians going to the same destination](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/shortest_path.html#exercise-2)' to determine the 1) length and 2)geometry of students to their schools.

Essentially I'm trying to write functions that use pgRouting the way ST_Distance and ST_MakeLine accept geometry from students and schools which we use frequently.

Here is the logic we use to get students 'straight line' distance to a particular school (works for multiple schools too):

```
select

stu.studentid
, sch.schnum
, ST_Distance(stu.geom, sch.geom)

from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu

, dpsdata."Schools_Current" as sch

where stu.studentid in ('750909', '818767', '768952')

and sch.schnum = '215'
```

The way ST_Distance accepts two geometries, and the where clause specifies which geometries to pass in (schnum, studentid's) is the same way I'm trying to get the pgRouting tools to work in a function.

I can get the 'single pedestrian' samples to work pointing to my existing student and school tables:

```
--one student to one school
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         length AS cost
        FROM osm.osm_ways',

     ---student
    (SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
     (select geom from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu where stu.studentid = '750909') limit 1 )::integer,  
---school
 (SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> 
 (select geom from dpsdata."Schools_Current" as sch where sch.schnum = '215') limit 1 ) 

   , directed := false
     );
```

However, I can't think of the logic that would generate the same in the 'multiple pedestrians' sample using the same method of passing in multiple geometry instances for each student:

**(note the use of the in statement to select which students I want to run  'multiple pedestrian' against)**

```
    --many students to one school
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
        SELECT gid AS id,
             source,
             target,
             length_m AS cost
            FROM osm.osm_ways',

--instead of passing in an array of ID's, get them from the source tables
        --ARRAY[84234, 38905, 107851], 149952

--student

        (SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
         (select geom from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu where stu.studentid in ( '750939', '814767', '768922')) limit 1)

    --school
         , (SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> 
     (select geom from dpsdata."Schools_Current" as sch where sch.schnum = '215') limit 1 ) 


        , directed := false
        );
```

The error returned is: *ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*

Is there either an error in logic or SQL that I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the the multi-student sub-query below you were using to replace the single student query:

```
--student
(SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
 (select geom from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu where stu.studentid in ( '750939', '814767', '768922')) limit 1)
```

The single-student sub-query below you were trying to "vectorize" seems to be finding the closest network vertex to a given student.

```
 ---student
(SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
 (select geom from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu where stu.studentid = '750909') limit 1 ),
```

The replacement above is incorrect in itself as you would be `ORDER BY` distance from `osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr` to multiple students. **The dimension on both sides of the `<->` operator don't match in general**, which will give you the `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery ...`.

There may be more succinct ways, but one way of solving the problem is to encapsulate that statement in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION closest_vertex_stu(stu_id bigint)
RETURNS bigint AS $$
  SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
    (select the_geom from ways_vertices_pgr as stu where stu.id = stu_id) limit 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And then call it to get the array needed by `pgr_dijkstra()` e.g.:

```
SELECT array_agg(closest_vertex_stu(stu.id)) 
 FROM ways_vertices_pgr as stu WHERE stu.id in ( '6549', '1458', '9224');
```

(which returns

```
  array_agg     
------------------
 {1458,6549,9224}
```

(Note: as the other answer pointed out, if you omit the `array_agg`, Postgres will give you **another** `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery`)

And finally plug it in:

```
--many students to one school --modified version
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
        SELECT gid AS id,
             source,
             target,
             length_m AS cost
            FROM ways',
--instead of passing in an array of ID's, get them from the source tables
        --ARRAY[84234, 38905, 107851], 149952
--student
        (SELECT array_agg(closest_vertex_stu(stu.id))
      FROM ways_vertices_pgr as stu WHERE stu.id in ( '6549', '1458', '9224') )
--school
         ,(SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> 
     (select the_geom from ways_vertices_pgr as sch where sch.id = '13224') limit 1 ) 
        , directed := false
        );
```

**Note** that I have used the `ways_vertices_pgr as stu` to mimic your actual student table (and similarly `sch` table); and changed `osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr` to `ways_vertices_pgr` etc. as I am using a more recent version (pgrouting 2.3 and Postgres 9.6). The `id` fields for students were also assumed to be `id` of type `bigint` (instead of `integer`). There may be other minor changes due to version differences.

Some outputs using the fake data noted above (which is the same as [the solution to the exercise you linked](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/the_solutions.html#sol-2)):

```
seq | path_seq | start_vid | node  | edge  |       cost       |     agg_cost     
-----+----------+-----------+-------+-------+------------------+------------------
   1 |        1 |      1458 |  1458 |  9579 | 122.730552004008 |                0
   2 |        2 |      1458 | 15780 |  9580 | 6.81560014546899 | 122.730552004008
   3 |        3 |      1458 |   341 |  9581 | 4.34905086403575 | 129.546152149477
   4 |        4 |      1458 |  6588 |   402 | 17.8063617725158 | 133.895203013513
   5 |        5 |      1458 |  8421 | 19113 | 14.0364441671311 | 151.701564786028
...
  33 |       33 |      1458 |   505 | 19236 | 44.5745770978563 | 1511.97228432811
  34 |       34 |      1458 | 13224 |    -1 |                0 | 1556.54686142597
  35 |        1 |      6549 |  6549 |  7019 | 87.8579034775688 |                0
  36 |        2 |      6549 |  4004 |  7018 | 10.3932702792749 | 87.8579034775688
...
115 |       70 |      9224 | 13224 |    -1 |                0 | 2491.75714906807
(115 rows)
```

Comment: Just fantastic - a few tweaks to match my table names and geom column names and I'm good to go - I can use this as a big query, rather than a function like ST_Distance, but a few more tweaks and I can pretty much get exactly what I want... many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error says, what is wrong: your sub-query returns more than one row:

```
(SELECT id FROM osm.osm_ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <->
         (select geom from dpsdata."Geo_Active_Student" as stu where stu.studentid in ( '750909', '818767', '768952')) limit 1)
```

Instead, it should return a single row with an array of id's, like:

```
ARRAY[84234, 38905, 107851]
```

You can change your query above to return all ID's as array instead of rows with the [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) function. So instead of `SELECT id ...` it should work to use:

```
SELECT array_agg(id) ...
```

Comment: that gives an error that the_geom must be in a group by, which after I figure that out, gives me the same "more than one row returned" error...

Comment: also wondering if I'm going the right direction here - how can existing analysis using functions like ST_Distance and ST_MakeLine take advantage of pgRouting instead? Pie in the sky for me for a few years now... still getting stumped on seemingly basic things (but have no experience in custom functions...)

Comment: Why do you need to `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` when you already query explicitly for certain student ID's or school numbers? The purpose subqueries isn't really clear to me.

Comment: the ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 are from samples by Regina where the geometry given in the subquery is used to find the closest node in the ways_vertices_pgr table using the <-> (this is the only place I've seen this operator before) and LIMIT 1 means only return the 1st NODE ID - so combined with the sample in the pgRouting Tutorial from 2016 Bonn... what I'm trying to do is mimic the ST_Distance and ST_Make line as they both take geometries from two tables (students, schools).

Comment: Daniel, I added some SQL to show how we use ST_Distance and what we'd like to do with pgRouting... hope that helps give more context...