# Route between two point layers following streets

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, routing, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a problem to be solved with shortest path route.

What I have:

- layer 1 with startpoints
- layer 2 with endpoints
- layer 3 with streets (lines)

These two point layers are originally the start and endpoints of a layer of lines, but now i'm looking for an alternate route for these lines, using the shortest path algorithm.

I want to calculate the **shortest path between these two point layers**. The two pointlayers have both an attribute where the startpoint and endpoint have the same unique value, so they can be connected on that attribute value I suppose.

I already did a try with **pgRouting**: i followed a tutorial and already did pgr_createTopology on the streetlayer, so the vertices of these streets are already made.

But now i'm stuck, can for example **pgr_dijkstra** be automised for a whole layer? (because each pointlayer contains +10.000 points)

My idea was to use nearest neighbour to link the start and endpoints to a vertice of the streets. And then use pgr_dijkstra on that streetlayer so that the shortest path is calculated when the values of the pointlayer are the same, so startpoint(UNIQUE_VALUE) = endpoint(UNIQUE_VALUE).

How is this possible, or does someone have another solution?

Comment: check the accepted answer here - i had the same problem with students and schools and found a solution in the answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231786/using-pgrouting-for-multiple-pedestrians-on-an-existing-table-of-students

Comment: But how can I implement the restriction that the startpoint and endpoint are from the same (original) line? I have implemented already all the nearest vertex of the street network into the 2 tables with start- and endpoints.

Comment: I think i'm very close! I have a table now with the startvertex and the endvertex that should be implememented in the pgr_dijkstra(). They are in a table with column1=startvertex and column2=endvertex. How can I now execute the whole table?