# pgRouting: Find source/target ID of edge closest to points in a separate layer for many-to-one routing

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a small road network which I have extracted from OSM and prepared for routing using OSM2PO. I also have a separate layer of points (postcode centroids). I wish to compute many-to-one routing between each point to a single destination.

In my research I have found many useful answers regarding how to undertake a many-to-one routing, but all these solutions require manually entering a source/target id for each origin edge. (The single destination is, of course, simple and I am happy to manually input that source/target id.)

Is there a way in which I could programatically find the nearest edge to each point and then pass the relevant source/target ID into the pgRouting algorithm, looping through for every point?

Here is a picture of my data in QGIS which may help clarify the situation:

[image]

Comment: If I read this as my problem of routing students to a single school, this solution worked beautifully for me: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/233502/9880 - let me know if you have questions!!